# Como exibir uma mensagem JavaScript em uma view asp.net MVC?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho esse código:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (Model.ErrorMessage))
{
     <Script>
         $ ("#ModalError').modal.('show.');
     </Script>

     Response.Write("<script>alert('Olá');</script>");

     HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('Olá');</script>");
}
```

Onde verifico se Model.Error mensagem é diferente de vazio, então eu queria dar um alerta para o usuário exibindo a mensagem de erro, mas nenhuma das forma que esta no meio dessa condição if esta dando certo.

Ja tentei assim também:

```
@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["erro"] as string))
{
    <script>alert(@ViewData["erro"]);</script>

}
```

Essa e uma parte da view.

Minha controller esta assim:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ErrorMessage))
                ViewData["erro"] = !String.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ErrorMessage) ? model.ErrorMessage : null;

            return this.View(model);
        }
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Você tentou com @Html.Raw("<script>alert("+ ViewData["erro"] as string +");</script>");  ?

Comment: Testei e não apareceu nada.

Comment: faltou as aspas simples @Html.Raw("<script>alert('"+ ViewData["erro"] as string +"');</script>");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo o erro esta que você tem que definir um um evento a essa ação acho que o correto seria no ready da pagina !

Bom acho que é isso para ter certeza precisaria ver o projeto !

Espero ter ajudado.. Boa Sorte ai !

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#modalError').modal();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>exemple</title> 
     <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div id="modalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Message.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Desde cedo tentando resolver, nem acredito que era só isso.

Comment: hahahaha acontece. .. problema resolvido ?

Answer (score 0):

Com *ViewBag*:

Na View, coloque:

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ViewBag.Erro))
{
    <script>alert('Olá');</script>
}
```

No Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
{
  ViewBag.Erro = model.ErrorMessage == null ? "" : model.ErrorMessage;
  return View();
}
```

---

Com *Model*:

Na View, coloque:

```
@model NamespaceCompletodaModel.LoginViewModel 

@if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage))
{
    <script>alert('Olá');</script>
}
```

No Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel model, SignInMessage message)
{
  model.ErrorMessage = model.ErrorMessage == null ? "" : model.ErrorMessage;
  return View(model);
}
```

---

Não é possível usar o Response através da View.

Comment: Já tentei exatamente da primeira forma que você informou, e mesmo assim não da certo.

Comment: Eu tenho que retornar um model dentro da view, se não da referência de objeto não definida, mas mesmo usando esse código informado e passando o model na view não da certo, fiz isso:
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Erro))
{
    <script>
        alert('Olá');
        alert(@Model.ErrorMessage);
        console.log(@Model.ErrorMessage);

    </script>

}

Na view e não foi

Comment: Desculpe. Fiz uma correção.

Comment: Ja testei, não vai

Comment: Se vc colocar somente "<script>alert('Olá');</script>" na view e "return View();" no controller, vai?

Comment: Também não, e eu não posso retornar uma view sem passar o model

Comment: Meu código esta exatamente desta forma.

Comment: Como você aciona o método Login?

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou utilizar

```
@Html.Raw("<script>............</script>");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz assim e funcionou.

**Controler:**

```
public class MensagemController : Controller
{
    // GET: Mensagem
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["erro"] = "Mensagem de Erro";

        return View();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@Html.Raw("<script>alert('" + ViewData["erro"] as string + "');</script>")
```